# Sugiyama for android

Tags: android, layout, hierarchy

Is their any Sugiyama library or source available for android for the hierarchical layout?
I have seen this link but its using JGraph and I could not find the JGraph and Sugiyama library for Android.

http://www.pedvizapi.org/doc/pedviz/algorithms/Sugiyama.html

http://chianti.ucsd.edu/svn/coreplugins/tags/Cyto-2.5.0-beta4/AutomaticLayout/src/org/jgraph/layout/SugiyamaLayoutAlgorithm.java

Answer (score 0):

there's a Sugiyama layout implementation as part of the modsl system, Apache license. source is [here](https://code.google.com/p/modsl/source/browse/#svn/trunk/modsl-core/src/main/java/org/modsl/core/agt/layout/sugiyama).

i was able to convert it reasonably easily to a mixed [Objective-C/Objective-C++ implementation](https://github.com/damiannz/digraph) based on digraph.

hth!